# Cannot install YouTube because "Could not get lock" / Unable to lock the administration directory"

Tags: software-installation, youtube, ubuntu-restricted-extras

```
abhimanyu@ABHIMANYU:~$ sudo apt-get install -y ubuntu-restricted-extras  
[sudo] password for abhimanyu:  
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)  
E:E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: just restart your machine and try again?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the packet manager is being used by some other application  which locks it.
You just need to follow the next few steps and everything is solved :

• Kill all the packages  anyway:

```
      killall -9 apt* dpkg
```

• If you ever use synaptic, you should make that:

```
      killall -9 apt* dpkg synaptic
```

•Having confirmed that there is no "rogue" pkg. managers running, check, remove, & rechecke the lock file:

```
      ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock
      rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
      ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

•Finally, just fix it up:

```
     aptitude safe-upgrade
     dpkg --configure -a
```

•In the end if required just update the file database using

```
     sudo updatedb
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a lot easier. You cannot use several programs at the same time to install software. You need to make sure there is no other software management tool running. Just check whether you have the ubuntu software centre open or whether you have synaptic running. If so, close them. If in doubt, just reboot or log out and log in again.